# how do i get the query which executed more time from a log file

Tags: shell, unix-timestamp, database-administration

I need the unix command to fetch out the query that got executed more than 1 sec from a log file using sed/awk. $11 is time stamp.

Pl suggest awk script to print all the query that executed more than 1 sec

the log file pattern looks as below,

```
"PUT /XXX/YYY/test/1/test/1/test/json/query HTTP/1.1" 111 111 5.019
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question! In your sample, the query is `PUT`... What kind of information are you searching for? What kind of log (server), which tool are you using for displaying logs?

Comment: Hi ,i am trying to take the query from a log file in unix.  In the PUT query above the 11th place holder is the time I am looking for .I want to pull out all the query from a log file log.txt whose time of execution is >1ms

Comment: There is no _11th place holder_ in your _log file pattern_.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.